# View wrapping Text tag in React Native complaining about text string

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code inside a component but the problem is when I remove the outer `View`, RN complains about `Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component..`. Well, I wrapped the text inside a `view` and `text` tag. Why the error. The below snippet works fine, errors out when outer view is taken off.

```
<View>
    {
        badgeCount > 0 && (<View style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                right: -6,
                top: -3,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                borderRadius: 6,
                width: 12,
                height: 12,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
            <Text style={{
                    color: 'white',
                    fontSize: 10,
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }}>
                {badgeCount}
            </Text>
        </View>)
    }
</View>
```

Full render method-

```
render() {
    const {name, badgeCount, color, size} = this.props;
    return (<View style={{
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
            margin: 5
        }}>
        <Ionicons name={name} size={size} color={color}/> {
            badgeCount > 0 && (<View style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    right: -6,
                    top: -3,
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    borderRadius: 6,
                    width: 12,
                    height: 12,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                }}>
                <Text style={{
                        color: 'white',
                        fontSize: 10,
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }}>
                    {badgeCount}
                </Text>
            </View>)
        }

    </View>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In render method if we have to render something based on a condition then we add condition using curly braces.

```
render(){
  return (
      <View>
       {toShowText &&
       <Text>Hello viewing</View>
       }
      </View>
   )}
```

In your case when you remove View outside curly braces.Render method considers it to be any text and force you to wrap in  component.That is why to use a conditional rendering you have to wrap curly braces in a view container

Comment: Then I have this unnecessary empty <View> left if toShowText is false. How to circumvent that? Second issue is, I am not removing the root View right at the top level of the render method, just removing an inner View. Render should not complain against that. Right?

Comment: in case "toShowText" is false then the view will not be rendered on screen because you are not specifying any height or width of the view.it will take space only when there will be any content inside the view. As far as second issue is concerned i am able to see only one view inside your render method.